# Is it possible to run server side validation for Ninja Forms using file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, ninja-forms

I've been banging my head all day on this last piece of my project.  I'm using Ninja Forms and looking to validate a string before submitting the form.  I have broken this into pieces and tested using simple string checks and it worked but when I try to use the file_get_contents() function it's just submitting without running the check.  The file realtor_info.txt contains the following: mikeoberdick@gmail.com - BP61AM.  The page is found here: https://www.rhwarranty.com/realtor-quote/

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data');

function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {
    $form_id = $form_data[ 'form_id' ];
    if ( $form_id = 4 ) {
        
        $email_field_id = 41;
        $coupon_field_id = 49;

        $email = $form_data['fields'][$email_field_id]['value'];
        $coupon = $form_data['fields'][$coupon_field_id]['value'];

        $string = $email . ' - ' . $coupon;
        $file = "https://rhwarranty.com/wp-content/themes/regal-home-warranty/stripe/realtor_info.txt";

        //check the file to see if the string exists
        if( strpos(file_get_contents($file),$string) !== false) {
            return $form_data;
        } else {
            $form_data['errors']['fields'][$coupon_field_id] = 'Something is not quite right here!';
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assign the value of the form in the if statement ?

Or if ( $form_id = 4 ) {
this should be
if ( $form_id == 4 ) {

Comment: I'm using the form ID so that I'm not running this conditional check on every form submission. It works so that's not the issue.

Comment: It works, but actually does nothing. 
`$form_id = 4` - assigning the variable (actually reassigning in your case)


 `$form_id == 4` - conditional check !



I try and the function is working. 

Another thing which you may check is weather the file_get_contents function is not blocked by the config of the server.

Comment: I checked the error log and there wasn't anything there about file permissions or anything. I was also able to run this function in a JavaScript fetch in another instance so I know it's accessible per the file permissions. What do you mean when you say that it's working?

Comment: I did a hardcode check of  the:

` strpos(file_get_contents($file),$string) !== false` and it works

Comment: Ok so it's working but not doing anything? Any idea why the form is submitting even if the email address in the form doesn't match the file contents?

Comment: Did you try to see what returns this:

`        $email = $form_data['fields'][$email_field_id]['value'];
        $coupon = $form_data['fields'][$coupon_field_id]['value'];` variables? Does this matchs the form, sometimes this modules has caches and ex. ..

Comment: This is where my PHP knowledge falls on its face. How do I log to console or print those variables?

Comment: So you have several ways: You could var_dump() them, but it may be difficult to see them along with the whole info. The other way is to log them as errors in the error log in php .. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php